# PHP SQL Injection - Executing and returing empty value

Tags: php

I have an IOS application that executes a PHP Script but when i test in the browser and in IOS i get empty string returned from PHP script call:

PHP Version is 5.2

This is the url i am calling :

http://hugt.co.uk/checkUserVerification.php?Email=tp_redo_c@hotmail.com&Password=ULLAFI01

But the echoed value is empty string. Is the script fine or am i making errors somewhere?

I was using other functions to call MYSQL but commented those out to check for SQL Injection so I'm not familiar with the code I'm using.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

        include "connect.php";


        $email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
        $password = $_REQUEST["Password"];

        $verificationCode = null;
        if(isset($_REQUEST['Verification'])){

            $verificationCode = $_REQUEST["Verification"];
        }

        $hasBeenVerified = 0;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT U_Verified, U_ID FROM U_User WHERE U_Email = ? AND U_Password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$stmt->bind_result($district);
        //$stmt->fetch();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $myrow = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();


        if($myrow){

            $hasBeenVerified = $myrow['U_Verified'];
            if($hasBeenVerified == 1){

                echo $myrow['U_ID'];
                exit();


            }else{

                if($verificationCode != null){

                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT U_VerificationCode, U_ID FROM U_User WHERE U_Email = ? AND U_Password = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result2 = $stmt->get_result();
                    $myrow2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
                    $stmt->close();

                    if($myrow2['U_VerificationCode'] == $verificationCode){

                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE U_User SET U_Verified = true WHERE U_Email = ?");
                        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $result3 = $stmt->get_result();
                        //$myrow3 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
                        $stmt->close();

                        if($result3){
                            echo $myrow2['U_ID'];
                            exit();
                        }else{
                            echo 'server error';
                            exit();
                        } 
                    }else{
                        echo 'invalid verification';
                        exit();
                    }




                }else{


                    echo 'no verification';
                    exit();
                }

            }



        }else{
            echo 'not registered';
            exit();
        }

        /**$hasBeenVerified = 0;
        $qryCheck = "SELECT U_Verified, U_ID FROM U_User WHERE U_Email = '$email' AND U_Password = '$password'";
        $resultCheck = mysqli_query($conn, $qryCheck);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultCheck);

        if($num_rows > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultCheck);
            $hasBeenVerified = $row[0]; 
            if($hasBeenVerified == 1){

                echo $row[1];
                exit();

            }else{

                if($verificationCode != null){

                    $qryCheck2 = "SELECT U_VerificationCode, U_ID FROM U_User WHERE U_Email = '$email' AND U_Password = '$password'";
                    $resultCheck2 = mysqli_query($conn, $qryCheck2);
                    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultCheck2);
                    if($row2[0] == $verificationCode){
                        $updateRecordVerified = 'UPDATE U_User SET U_Verified = true WHERE U_Email = "$email"';
                        $resultCheck3 = mysqli_query($conn, $updateRecordVerified);
                        if($resultCheck3){
                            echo $row2[1];
                            exit();
                        }else{
                            echo 'server error';
                            exit();
                        }                                                   
                    }else{
                        echo 'invalid verification';
                        exit();
                    }

                }else{
                    //echo 'hhh' . $row[0];
                    echo 'no verification';
                    exit();             
                }


            }       


        }else{
            echo 'not registered';
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);**/
        $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: What is the question? What part of the posted code is relevant? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: http://hugt.co.uk/checkUserVerification.php?Email=tp_redo_c@hotmail.com&Password=ULLAFI01 this is what i am executing in the browser but nothing seems to happen or no result is echoed back

Comment: You do not have Verification in your URL

Comment: I'm just testing email and password i can test verification after

Comment: All i want to do is pass in the email and password so that i can log in but the returned result is empty and I'm inserting the right username and password that is stored in the database and the user has been verified

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

            include "connect.php";


            $email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
            $password = $_REQUEST["Password"];

            $verificationCode = null;
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Verification'])){

                $verificationCode = $_REQUEST["Verification"];
            }

            $hasBeenVerified = 0;
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT U_Verified, U_ID FROM U_User WHERE U_Email = ? AND U_Password = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($verified, $uId);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();


            if($uId){

                $hasBeenVerified = $verified;
                if($hasBeenVerified == 1){

                    echo $uId;
                    exit();


                }else{

                    if($verificationCode != null){

                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT U_VerificationCode, U_ID FROM U_User WHERE U_Email = ? AND U_Password = ?");
                        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result($codeVerification, $uId2);
                        $stmt->fetch();             
                        $stmt->close();

                        if($codeVerification == $verificationCode){

                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE U_User SET U_Verified = true WHERE U_Email = ?");
                            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->close();

                            echo $uId;
                            exit();

                        }else{
                            echo 'invalid verification';
                            exit();
                        }




                    }else{


                        echo 'no verification';
                        exit();
                    }

                }



            }else{
                echo 'not registered';
                exit();
            }

            $mysqli->close();
        ?>
```